# Parse string using Java Regex Pattern?

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have the below java string in the below format.

```
String s = "City: [name:NYK][distance:1100] [name:CLT][distance:2300] [name:KTY][distance:3540] Price:"
```

Using the java.util.regex package matter and pattern classes I have to get the output string int the following format:

```
Output: [NYK:1100][CLT:2300][KTY:3540]
```

Can you suggest a RegEx pattern which can help me get the above output format?

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Answer (score 18):

You can use this regex `\[name:([A-Z]+)\]\[distance:(\d+)\]` with Pattern like this :

```
String regex = "\\[name:([A-Z]+)\\]\\[distance:(\\d+)\\]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
while (matcher.find()) {                                                
    result.append("[");
    result.append(matcher.group(1));
    result.append(":");
    result.append(matcher.group(2));
    result.append("]");
}

System.out.println(result.toString());
```

**Output**

```
[NYK:1100][CLT:2300][KTY:3540]
```

- [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xxuW0O/1)
- `\[name:([A-Z]+)\]\[distance:(\d+)\]` mean get two groups one the upper letters after the `\[name:([A-Z]+)\]` the second get the number after `\[distance:(\d+)\]`

---

Another solution from [@tradeJmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175606/parse-string-using-java-regex-pattern/45175896?noredirect=1#comment77320968_45175896) you can use this regex :

```
String regex = "\\[name:(?<name>[A-Z]+)\\]\\[distance:(?<distance>\\d+)\\]";
```

So you can easily get the results of each group by the name of group instead of the index like this :

```
while (matcher.find()) {                                                
    result.append("[");
    result.append(matcher.group("name"));
    //----------------------------^^
    result.append(":");
    result.append(matcher.group("distance"));
    //------------------------------^^
    result.append("]");
}
```

Comment: Pretty much exactly how I would have done it. My only addition (and this is somewhat a matter of preference) is that the capture groups could be named, e.g. `name:(?<name>[A-Z]+)`, and then accessed as `matcher.group("name")`. Just makes it really clear at the access point exactly what segment you're trying to access.

Comment: this is good way @tradeJmark to use `name:(?<name>[A-Z]+)`, and then accessed as `matcher.group("name")` honestly it is the first time i see it, i already test it and it work very well `String regex = "\\[name:(?<name>[A-Z]+)\\]\\[distance:(?<distance>\\d+)\\]";` i will add to my answer if you don't mind :)

Comment: sure, definitely add it, if you like it.

Answer (score 4):

**If the format of the string is fixed, and you always have just 3 `[...]` groups inside to deal with**, you may define a block that matches `[name:...]` and captures the 2 parts into separate groups and use a quite simple code with `.replaceAll`:

```
String s = "City: [name:NYK][distance:1100] [name:CLT][distance:2300] [name:KTY][distance:3540] Price:";
String matchingBlock = "\\s*\\[name:([A-Z]+)]\\[distance:(\\d+)]";
String res = s.replaceAll(String.format(".*%1$s%1$s%1$s.*", matchingBlock), 
    "[$1:$2][$3:$4][$5:$6]");
System.out.println(res); // [NYK:1100][CLT:2300][KTY:3540]
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/yAGvoa) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XbUbOX/1).

The block pattern matches:

- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\\[name:`  - a literal `[name:` substring
- `([A-Z]+)` - Group n capturing 1 or more uppercase ASCII chars (`\\w+` can also be used)
- `]\\[distance:`  -  a literal `][distance:` substring
- `(\\d+)`  - Group m capturing 1 or more digits
- `]` - a `]` symbol.

In the `.*%1$s%1$s%1$s.*` pattern, the groups will have 1 to 6 IDs (referred to with `$1` - `$6` backreferences from the replacement pattern) and the leading and final `.*` will remove start and end of the string (add `(?s)` at the start of the  pattern if the string can contain line breaks).